# Upon stripe customer creation save Customer model on server

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

The stripe customer is being successfully created on stripes servers but I need a representation on my server so I created the Customer model all it has is the user_id and the stripe_id. Heres the code I have been trying but it does not work.. I think the problem is with retrieving the actual stripe id for that particular user..

```
 # Create stripe customer
        stripe.Customer.create()
        new_customer = Customer(
            user=request.user,
            stripe_id=id,
        )
        new_customer.save()
```

This snippet of code is inside the user registration view, and it runs after the user is authenticated and logged in

So what appears in the stripe_id field is:

```
<built-in function id>
```

Comment: are you assigning stripe.Customer.create() to a variable, e.g. `customer = stripe.Customer.create()` --- then you should be able to get `customer.id` (cus_xxxyyyzzz)

Comment: @duck ok got that working now. How would I save the card details? customer.card.id for example or customer.card.last4 does not work.

Comment: Take a look at the Customer object, you could get the card id (or other details from `customer.sources.data[n]` so if a single card were attached you could get `customer.sources.data[0].id`, etc https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object